# Sqlite console doesn't accept accents

Tags: macos, sqlite, console

Im trying to import a database from SQL to Sqlite.
I have 126 registers with separate inserts to import to my local version of the database, when I paste the inserts in to the console all accents dissapear, and the registers are inserted withouht accents.
Is there a way to prevent the console from doing that?

Im working on a mac, I want to export this database for an iphone app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the console is not working for pasting text, you may use the `.read` command of the sqlite shell to get the insert commands from a file. See the [Command Line Shell documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html).

Comment: Great, Im actually using sqlite3 thedatabase.db < mysqlinserts.sql which works and is basicly the same idea, thanks!